# Permission denied (publickey). Bitnami AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, bitnami

I'm having trouble ssh-ing into my Bitnami AWS instance.  I'm pretty new to developing in general so I'm sure I could have missed something in the docs but I did chmod 600 and also tried 400 to my bitnami-hosting.pem and I use this command.  I checked the posts and non of the solutions I found helped out.  Any ideas?

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/bitnami-hosting.pem bitnami@ec2-52-10-192-39.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

I tried using the public and private IPs too.
and this is the return

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/adam/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/adam/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-52-10-192-39.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [52.10.192.39] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/adam/.ssh/bitnami-hosting.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/adam/.ssh/bitnami-hosting.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 44:de:04:21:c6:8c:08:9f:a6:6d:b1:48:a2:cb:ab:2f
debug1: Host 'ec2-52-10-192-39.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/adam/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/adam/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/adam/.ssh/bitnami-hosting.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you 100% positive you are using the right ssh key and not a different one?

Comment: Not 100%.  I went to Bitnami's site, found the server section and created a new key, like the docs said/hinted at.  Then I downloaded it and moved it to my ~/.ssh/ dir.  After I did that, I did 
`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/bitnami-hosting.pem`.  It's the only .pem file I have called bitnami-hosting.pem and the ssh command didn't error out with anything like "file not found" so I'm guessing I've got the right one.

Comment: You cannot create a key *after* you launched the server. You need to use the same key that you selected when you created the original server.

Comment: I gave up on it and created my own AMI but I am betting you're 100% right and that was my problem, Daniel.  Thanks for the help!